# How do I apply my styles to an entire Google Doc

Tags: google-docs

I have evolved my default Google Docs styles over time, and would now like to apply them to some older docs that use older (and sometimes various versions) of them.

How do I apply the current versions of my styles to *entire documents* where some text may be using older styles?